# Scala warning erasure in case

Tags: scala, warnings, pattern-matching, type-erasure, case-statement

I have the following pattern matching case in a scala function:

```
def someFunction(sequences: Iterable[Seq[Int]]):Seq[Int] = sequences match{
    case Seq() => Seq(1)
    case _ => ...
    ...
}
```

And I get the following warning:

```
warning: non variable type-argument A in type pattern Seq[A] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
case Seq(_) => Seq(1)
        ^
one warning found
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is a bit spurious, and will not be present on Scala 2.10. In fact, I think it's a regression from Scala 2.8 (that is, it is not present there).

The reason for the warning is that it interprets `Seq(_)` to mean `Seq(_: Seq[Int])`, since that's the type parameter of `sequences`, and then complaining that it can't guarantee that `Int` there, since, at compile time, that will be erased.  As I said, it's spurious.